# Is there a way to expand the variables viewer by default in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In VSCode, when you run code interactively and open the variables viewer, there is a lot of empty space, and the entries are cut off:
[Default variables viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpLaM.png)

What I end up doing is to manually expand the viewer, every time I open up the variables:
[Expanded variables viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47rmU.png)

However, whenever you close the variables and reopen them, it reverts back to the default view. Is there a way to have the variables expanded by default?